# Image Map Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-processing

I want to make an image map editor like this one

http://www.maschek.hu/imagemap

Are there any jquery plugin to do so ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This image map editor can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/imgmap/.

Pretty late response, but maybe someone will find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen a jQuery plugin to do exactly that, but it wouldn't be too hard to create.

There are several jQuery plugins available to select an area on an image, a good example may be [imgAreaSelect](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/). You could allow visitors to upload an image, then serve imgAreaSelect with a button "add to image map" which stores the coordinates and resets the image selection. Repeating this would add more rectanges to the map. A final button would generate HTML imagemap code based on the stored selections.

Hope that helps point you in the right direction

Comment: thank you. But the ImgAreaSelect by default doesn't support multiple selection. That's my problem.

Comment: That's why I suggested doing it one at a time. Make a selection, click a button labelled "Add to imagemap" which appends it to an array of coordinates and clears the selection ready for the next selection.

Comment: i already did it before. And my problem to solve is how to hilite all selected coordinate on the current image which is saved in array var. Since the tag <area /> doesn't support direct styling or css. Correct me if i'm wrong. I was thinking to use div as the layer up on the selected coordinate and setup z-index. But i don't know how to generate it so the div size and screen location is precisely up on the selected coordinate.

Comment: There is now a fork of ImgAreaSelect that does support multiple selection: https://github.com/stawek/imgareaselect